# How to scale physicsBody?

Tags: ios, ios7, cocos2d-iphone

When I scale a CCSprite with a physicsbody attached the physics body doesn't scale (I have debugDraw on). How do I scale the physicsBody?

I found this code to change the radius of a circular physical body but it doesn't work on cocos2d v3..

```
    for(ChipmunkCircleShape* newShape in self.chipmunkObjects)
    {
        if([newShape isKindOfClass:[ChipmunkCircleShape class]]) {
            cpCircleShapeSetRadius([newShape shape],[newShape radius]*scale); // Unsafe Resize
            cpCircleShapeSetOffset([newShape shape],ccpMult([newShape offset],scale));
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you include "chipmunk_unsafe.h"? Functions cpCircleShapeSetRadius  and cpCircleShapeSetOffset are defined there. Read also the comment [here](http://chipmunk-physics.net/forum/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=2197). Hope it helps :)